# Tomcat7 OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space

Tags: tomcat, grails, richfaces, tomcat7

I have `tomcat 7.0.47`, one project in `grails 2.3.7 and 2 in RichFaces 4.3.4 in windows 2003` server`(2Gb RAM)`. If I load 2 of them in `tomcat` - they work, but if I load all of them (3) - I see permgen `outofmemory error`.
I tried change `MaxPermSize in tomcat` but it not get result. The grails project is big. Can I do something with projects to optimize PermGet memory usage?

I changed `tomcat` to `GlassFish 3.1.2`. Now it is enough memory for all projects. But I have a problem with Easygrig plugin in my Grails project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java applications are allowed to use only a limited amount of memory. The exact amount of memory your particular application can use is specified during application startup. To make things more complex, Java memory is separated into different regions one of which - named permgen - you have exhausted in this case.

The main cause for the “java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space“: either too many classes or too big classes are being loaded to the permanent generation. In your case, I doubt that you have actually managed to load 2GB of data into the permgen though, I suspect that either you have misspelled the property (-XX:MaxPermSize) in your Tomcat configuration or that this configuration is not picked up by Tomcat at all.

You can verify whether the configuration change was picked up by for example by attaching jconsole to the Tomcat process, similar to the following example:

```
my-machine me$ jps
3160 Jps
1514 org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap
my-machine me$ jconsole 1514
```

Navigate to the VM summary TAB and you should see the parameters actually used by the Tomcat instance.

Answer (score 0):

No. Your system resources are insufficient. In Java's Memory Model, the Permenant Generation is where classes, methods, and other *permanent* things live. In order to reduce PermGen capacity, you need to reduce permanent application members. You'll be hard pressed for that on 2gb RAM.

Good luck!

Comment: I think 2GB should be enough for 3 projects

Comment: Think what you want; your JVM is telling you the truth though :-)

Comment: I agree with Daniel, you should check JVM memory consumption at runtime by using any tool like JConsole and you will get answer